# what is the asterisk used for in vector type specification?

Tags: c++

```
vector<a*> array;
```

There is an asterisk after the specification of vector type. What is the use of that asterisk? Are we trying to declare that vector as a pointer? If so, shouldn't the asterisk be used before the variable name instead of including it in the type bracket `<>` ?

Comment: You are declaring that `array` is a `vector` *of* pointers! (That is, each member of the vector will be a pointer to an `a` class object.)

Comment: That makes the vector element type a pointer to `a`.

Comment: The `*` is not after the template type (vector type), it is part of the template type. (You could define a type alias for a pointer to `a` with `using a_ptr_t = a*;` and use that `vector<a_ptr_t> array;` and that would be equal to `vector<a*> array;`)

Answer (score 2):

> there is an asterisk after the specification of vector type

No, there is an asterisk after `a`.

> what is the use of that asterisk?

It says that the type is "[pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to `a`".

The vector is a vector of pointers to `a`s.

> are we trying to declare that vector as an pointer?

No. We're declaring a vector that *contains* pointers.

> if so, shouldnt the asterisk be used before the variable name instead of including it in the type bracket<>?

Yes, that is how you would make the *vector* into a pointer.

Comment: Tysm! that cleared everything. I was having so much trouble understanding mixing between pointers and vectors for 6 hours.